# load custom response in datatable using server side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am trying to load datatable from ajax response and then perform server-side processing. using [this example](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/13462/loading-json-from-external-ajax-call-into-datatable)

this is the response I am receiving from server :

```
{"msg":null,"code":null,"status":null,"result":[{"aNumber":"3224193861","bNumber":"3215910681","dateTime":"2017-06-05 09:44:22.0","duration":778,"imei":"47350901163665"},{"aNumber":"3224193861","bNumber":"3028540439","dateTime":"2017-04-26 18:53:23.0","duration":266,"imei":"31489802062929"}],"draw":1,"limit":1000,"recordsFiltered":13419,"recordsTotal":13419}
```

this my javascript code to handle ajax and datatable.

```
function showDataTable(anumber, startdate, enddate) {
    var cdrReqParams = {};
    cdrReqParams.draw = '1';
    cdrReqParams.offset = 0;
    cdrReqParams.newRequest = '1';
    cdrReqParams.totalRecords = '1';
    cdrReqParams.lookInCol = 'aNumber';
    cdrReqParams.lookInVal = anumber;
    cdrReqParams.fromDate = startdate;
    cdrReqParams.toDate = enddate;

    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(cdrReqParams);
    console.log(jsonStr);

    API.call("http://localhost:8050/phpservice/json.php", 'POST', function(data) {
        basicData = data.result;
        console.log(basicData);
        oTable = $("#table").dataTable({
            bJQueryUI: true,
            bPaginate: true,
            sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            aaData: [basicData],
            aoColumns: [{
                "sTitle": "ANUMBER",
                "mData": "aNumber"
            }, {
                "sTitle": "BNUMBER",
                "mData": "bNumber"
            }, {
                "sTitle": "DATETIME",
                "mData": "dateTime"
            }, {
                "sTitle": "DURATION",
                "mData": "duration"
            }, {
                "sTitle": "IMEI",
                "mData": "imei"
            }]
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }, jsonStr);
}
```

By doing this, I am receiving 2 errors

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter
>   'aNumber' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error,
>   please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

and

> Invalid JSON Response.

Is there any workaround for this type of problem, In which first, you will perform ajax call and from received data, you will populate datatable with server side processing ??

I hope someone will give me a hint at least.

Answer (score 0):

With datatable 1.10,(i think you may be using an earlier version), you can populate and format the data in the cells, by using the columns.data property:

```
  columns: [             
             { data: "", defaultContent: " " },               

             { data: null, 
               defaultContent: " ", 
               render: function (data, type, row, meta) { 
                                return data.ID; 
               } 
             }
           ]
```